# Split two different strings into one array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

So obviously you can split a string into an array, like this:

```
var arrayOfStrings = originalString.split(' ');
```

But is it possible to somehow easily create an array of two splits?

Eg:

```
var arrayOfStrings = originalString.split(' ') && secondString.split(' ')
```

**Obviously the above is pseudo code and not valid**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
originalString.split(' ').concat(secondString.split(' '))
```

For reference - [Array concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, with [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

> The `concat()` method returns a new array comprised of the array on which it is called joined with the array(s) and/or value(s) provided as arguments.

```
var arrayOfStrings = originalString.split(' ').concat(secondString.split(' '));
```

Answer (score 1):

just use [contact()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method

```
originalString.split(' ').concat(secondString.split(' '))
```